# Will dividing an NSUInteger by 2 result in a whole number?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am trying to do this in Objective-C:

```
self.nsarray.count/2
```

If the count is equal to 5, will the result be 5/2 = 2.5 or 5/2 = 2?

I am NSLogging the answer and it only shows me 2. I'm not sure if that's the actual answer or if's 2, because I am forced to use the `%u` format to log the answer. Please also explain the 'why' of this result.

Answer (score 0):

The division with two whole numbers in Objective-C always produces a whole number as a result, in your case it would be NSUInteger, and `2` is a valid result in this case. To get a result with floating point at least one of your operands should be `float` typed, or at least one of them should be casted to `float`, so here's some options:

```
// Second part of division is float, so result is float as well
float result = self.array.count/2.

// First part of division is float, so result is float as well
float result2 = (float)self.array.count/2 // or you can type ((float)self.array.count)/2 for more clearance
```

Note that casting result to `float` isn't valid on your case, for instance in `(float) (5/2)` the result would be a whole number of type float (2.0) as you only cast a `NSIntger` to `float`

Floats are usually formatted in NSLog format as %f or %g

Comment: CGFloat is a very bad choice - on 32 bit systems it has only 24 bit of precision, so you'll get the wrong result if there are more than about 16 million items. And it's a bug that only affects power users and will never be found during testing. Use double.

Comment: The CG in CGFloat stands for  Core Graphics. Don't use CGFloat except for coordinates of graphical objects.

Comment: @gnasher729 good point on `CGFloat`/`float` types, changed my answer referring to that... but what comes to using `double` instead of `float` - would we really get a wrong result, since we're only dividing by 2? So that the fractional part would have only 1 digit in it (5 or 0) so shouldn't we be good with `float` precision?